# I want to get variable values from jenkins in my python code for desired capabilities

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, saucelabs

I want to pass desired capabilities from jenkins to sauce lab

I have written my code in python

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platform'] = os.getenv('platform','SELENIUM_PLATFORM')
desired_caps['browserName'] = os.getenv('browserName','SELENIUM_BROWSER')
desired_caps['version'] = os.getenv('version','SELENIUM_VERSION')
context.browser = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://USER_NAME:KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
```

Getting this error on jenkins while running the build:

```
Starting pre-build for Sauce Labs plugin
Finished pre-build for Sauce Labs plugin
$ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins6037287030698812464.bat
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Misconfigured -- 
Unsupported OS/browser/version/device combo: OS: 'SELENIUM_PLATFORM', 
Browser: 'selenium_browser', Version: 'SELENIUM_VERSION.', Device: 
'unspecified'

Executing before all - creating benemax admin with owner permission to use it 
everywhere
User data: {}
Exception WebDriverException: Message: Misconfigured -- Unsupported 
OS/browser/version/device combo: OS: 'SELENIUM_PLATFORM', Browser: 
'selenium_browser', Version: 'SELENIUM_VERSION.', Device: 'unspecified'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Starting post-build for Sauce Labs plugin
Updating the custom data field for jobs with Jenkins build info for analytics
Stopped/completed/updated 0 jobs
Finished post-build for Sauce Labs plugin
Starting Sauce Labs test publisher
The Sauce OnDemand plugin is configured, but no session IDs were found in the 
test output.
Finished Sauce Labs test publisher
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `os.getEnv` wrong.

`os.getenv('version','SELENIUM_VERSION')` should most likely be just `os.getenv('SELENIUM_VERSION')`

The second parameter of the function is default value, the first is the environment variable you want to get. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.getenv

Now what happens is that you try to get the value of an environment variable called `version`, which does not exist, and then it defaults back to the literal string `'SELENIUM_VERSION'`.

Comment: Thanks this is working can you please help me with the report generation part.